# MODX Где лучше хранить чанки?

Tags: modx

Если хранить чанки в tpl вместо бд, то сайт будет работать быстрее? Предполагается что в обоих случаях будет использован fenom и только fenom вместо дефолтного парсера. Я до конца не вникал в движок, но мне кажется, что использование tpl позволит снять лишнюю нагрузку с сервера и, тем самым, увеличить производительность сайта, особенно при высоком онлайне

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разница в скорости не сильно заметная на мой взгляд, но файлы чуть быстрее, вы правы. На modx.pro у Василия кажется были замеры на этот счет.